# Use a SQL Server database in a UWP app (The Name does not exist in the current context)

Tags: c#, sql-server, xaml, uwp

I am trying to follow the Use a SQL Server database in a UWP app tutorial found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases

I have followed the tutorial to the letter but keep getting the same errors in the same place.

[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyVMk.png)

I am using the Employee table instead of the Products table as in the tutorial but I have tried using te product table as per the tutorial and it results in errors in the same places.

For some reason it cannot seem to reference the ObservableCollection method from the product/employee class and cannot bind the attributes in the xaml file.

Employee.cs in place of product class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WinApp
{
    public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string TitleOfCourtesy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string HomePhone { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }

        public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public int ReportsTo { get; set; }
        public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
        public Employee Manager { get; set; }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }



        public ObservableCollection<Employee> GetEmployees(string connectionString)
        {
            const string GetEmployeesQuery = "select * FROM Employee";

            var employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText = GetEmployeesQuery;
                            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    var emp = new Employee();
                                    emp.EmployeeID = reader.GetInt16(0);
                                    emp.LastName = reader.GetString(1);
                                    emp.FirstName = reader.GetString(2);

                                    employees.Add(emp);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return employees;
            }
            catch (Exception eSql)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + eSql.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Error found atMainPage.xaml.cs, GetEmployees does not exist in the current context:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace WinApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            InventoryList.ItemsSource = GetEmployees((App.Current as App).ConnectionString);
        }
    }

}
```

MainPage.xaml where binding error exists at :

```
<Page
    x:Class="WinApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WinApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAcrylicWindowBrush}">
            <RelativePanel>
                <ListView Name="InventoryList"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True"
                  Margin="20">
                    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                                <TextBlock Text="ID" Margin="8,0" Width="50" Foreground="DarkRed" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Product description" Width="300" Foreground="DarkRed" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Packaging" Width="200" Foreground="DarkRed" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Price" Width="80" Foreground="DarkRed" />
                                <TextBlock Text="In stock" Width="80" Foreground="DarkRed" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Employee">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <TextBlock Name="ItemId"
                                    Text="{x:Bind EmployeeID}"
                                    Width="50" />
                                <TextBlock Name="ItemName"
                                    Text="{x:Bind FirstName}"
                                    Width="300" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind LastName}"
                                   Width="200" />

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </RelativePanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: what is `DateTime?` ?  how can a datetime be null?

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetEmployees` method is defined in the `Employee` class, which cannot be used directly in the `MainPage` class.

Try this:

1. Modify the `GetEmployees` method to be a static method so that it can be called by the class

```cs
public static ObservableCollection<Employee> GetEmployees(string connectionString)
{
    //...
}
```

2. Add the name of the class before the call

```cs
InventoryList.ItemsSource = Employee.GetEmployees((App.Current as App).ConnectionString);
```

If you do not add the corresponding reference, the corresponding type (such as `Employee`) will have a wavy line in the code editor. Move the cursor to the wavy line, there will be a small light bulb, after clicking, you can introduce the corresponding namespace (this also applies to XAML).

Thanks.